# VirtualBox Centos OS blank screen error

Tags: centos, virtualbox, 64bit

I have a 64 machine with a 64 windows 10 operating system. I am using virtualbox to install CentOs OS. For some reason in the dropdown menu in VirtualBox that helps me build my new virtual machine, I see the Version of Linux, as a matter of fact, ALL versions of ALL types of operating systems only have the (32-bit) as the only option.

For example I would not have the option to install FreeBSD 64 Bit, Windows 10 64 Bit etc... I need to have the virtual box give me the option of 64 Bit with Redhat, because I was told that CentOS's option is Redhat. Again all I see are 32 bit versions of the operating systems when I need to see Redhat 64. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of Virtualbox?

Comment: follow the virtual box documentation link below to host 64bit guest OS's [link: host 64bit guest OS's](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)

Comment: You should enable hardware virtualization in your BIOS (Intel VT-x or AMD-V). Otherwise you will be unable to run 64 bit guests. Cheers.